# MPMoviePlayerController setCurrentPlaybackTime becomes zero when doing play

Tags: objective-c, playback, mpmovieplayer, playsound

[playerView setCurrentPlaybackTime:5.100000];

```
LOG -> playerView.currentPlaybackTime = @"5.100000"
[playerView play];
LOG -> playerView.currentPlaybackTime = @"0"
```

In other cases this happens

```
LOG -> playerView.currentPlaybackTime = @"25.000000"
[playerView play];
LOG -> playerView.currentPlaybackTime = @"23.156467"
```

I tried using [playerView prepareToPlay] before play, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to switch to AVPlayer

setCurrentPlayback is

```
int32_t timeScale = playerView.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(value, timeScale);
[playerView seekToTime:time toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

Duration is

```
CMTime duration = playerView.currentItem.asset.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```

Same pause and Play functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start playback from a certain value you need to set the `initialPlaybackTime` property on your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance, to the value that you wish to playback to start from.